# how to ask xml question in stackoverflow

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, xml

xml is omitted from the question text. the reference has nothing about this ultra rare language..

-thanks

Comment: A quick answer, indent your xml 4 spaces.  It will show up.  Or just put it in and note that there is invisible xml, we'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select XML.
2. Click the `Format Code` button (101010) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
3. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Already fixed his question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355778/how-to-present-a-type-of-an-element-in-xml-schema).