# How do I post several lines of XML which happen to follow a bullet point?

Tags: support

I thought [the four spaces were supposed to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/how-to-ask-xml-question-in-stackoverflow). And they do, unless there is a bullet point right before them. How can I make this work?

Example:

- Here's some XML:

(it's there, in the source, but not displayed)

Comment: Yay!  I knew this was a duplicate.  And I found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/code-blocks-after-a-list-but-not-within-a-list-in-markdown-is-it-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to intent by 8 spaces.  This is a known bug/feature

- See what I do:

  ```
  <ThisWas indented="8 spaces" />
  ```

Also, you can 'break out' of the list using an xml comment or something similar

- See what I do again:

```
<ThisWas indented="4 spaces" but="I put an xml comment between the two" />
```

[Link to source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/e76229e9-585e-4b56-8f42-85c3e7851e7e/view-source)

Comment: So there's no way to "break out of" the bullet point, short of inserting a paragraph?

Comment: @rom, do you want the xml in the bullet, or after?

Comment: @rom, either way it is kind of hackey. (See my edit)